# How to remove dashes from data in google sheets and then execute a forEach loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to loop a function with different variables which are phone numbers from a column in google sheets.

I can loop it if I leave the data as is.

But when I need to transform them into E164 format (+1112223333) I can't do the loop because in order to remove the dashes I use the toString().replace() function, but then in converts the whole column into one string.

I dont want to remove the dashes on the spreadsheet itself, only by code

If I leave it like this it works...

```
function getNumbers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 2, ss.getDataRange().getLastRow()-1)
  var getnumber = range.getValues();
getnumber.forEach(sendText);
}
```

But like this it doesn't....

```
function getNumbers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 2, ss.getDataRange().getLastRow()-1)
  var getnumber = range.getValues().toString().replace(/-/g,"");
getnumber.forEach(sendText);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

The value retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. In your script, this array is converted to the string. By this, when this is used with `forEach`, an error occurs. I think that the reason of issue is this. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var getnumber = range.getValues().toString().replace(/-/g,"");
```

#### To:

```
var getnumber = range.getValues().map(([b]) => [b.toString().replace(/-/g,"")]);;
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: How can I prefix with +1 to get +12223334444

Comment: @jack Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `prefix with +1 to get +12223334444`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? For example, what you need is `var getnumber = range.getValues().map(([b]) => ["+1" + b.toString().replace(/-/g,"")]);`?

Comment: It worked to remove dashes. I also need to add **+1** to the begining of each number

Comment: @jack Thank you for replying. About it, how about the additional script in my previous replying?